# How to build sqlite VFS into the library

Tags: sqlite, vfs

I am trying to compile SQLite into a library which another application is then going to link against.  I am not able to compile SQLite directly into that application for reasons which are beyond the scope of this question.

However, I need a VFS to be available which by default is not.  In trying to figure out how to get this working I am trying to get the [vfstrace](https://www.sqlite.org/src/doc/trunk/src/test_vfstrace.c) shim to be made available to the application which is linking to SQLite.  This will easily prove that it is working as I can log SQLite VFS activity from the shim and see that it is actually being used when the application calls SQLite.

How do I do this?  All the examples I have found show the case of when you have a source file (such as shell.c) and you compile it, sqlite3.c and test_vfstrace.c to produce an executable. However, I do not have this luxury.  I could compile sqlite.c and test_vfstrace.c and generate the libsqlite3.so library file, but there is no "main" function in which to call vfstrace_register so that the VFS is actually available.  Is there some other hook for the library case where I can set this up?   If no, how do I make a new VFS available?

Comment: You should be able to add the source file to your project and use it directly (combined with `sqlite3_open_v3()` to use the right vfs after registering it.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is initialized via the `sqlite3_initialize()` function, which is called automatically when various functions such as `sqlite3_open()` are called by the user, although it is a no-op on subsequent invocations.   This function in turn calls the OS specific initialization function `sqlite3_os_init()`.  This is the function that initializes all the VFSes that are built into SQLite.

For the example VFS given, append test_vfstrace.c to the amalgamation and then put a call like this in `sqlite3_os_init()` right before the return statement:

```
  vfstrace_register("trace",0,(int(*)(const char*,void*))fputs,stderr,1);
```

Then build the library with these modifications.

The last parameter's value of `1` will make this VFS be the default, so if you don't want trace messages printed for every SQLite operation performed via code linked the library you just created change this to `0` and explicitly specify this VFS when opening a database to trace the calls for.  For instance, specify the `SQLITE_USE_URI` [compile time option](https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#use_uri), and then pass a filename of the [form](https://www.sqlite.org/uri.html): `"file:database.db?vfs=unix"` where "`database.db`" is the actual name of the file to open.